# @autowired Did not work in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, inversion-of-control, autowired

I developed a basic app containing 2 projects. First one is data layer and the second is a web app (mvc project)

**data layer** contains the following

```
@Entity
@Table(name="users")
public class User implements Serializable {
.....
}

public interface UserBase {
.....
  }

  @Repository
  public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository <User, Long>{
  }



   @Service
   public class UserImpl implements UserBase {  
   private final UserRepository repository; 
   @Autowired
   public UserImpl(UserRepository repository) { 
   this.repository = repository;
    ......
   }


  @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)  
  @ContextConfiguration("Config/applicationContext.xml")
  public class testcase1 {

    @Autowired
private UserImpl userImpl;

   @Test
   public void test() {
   ..... 
   UserImpl.save(user);
   .....
   }
```

**web app**
    @Controller
    public class ManageUser {

```
@Autowired
UserImpl userImpl;

@RequestMapping("/addUser/")
public ModelAndView addUser() {
UserImpl.save(user);
.....
}
}
```

When I run the unit test the code succeeded and no error found.
But when I put the output jar from data layer into the spring  mvc web app the lib folder and added reference to the data layer in the build bath  , I have an error message  
 **Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.my.domin.impl.UserImpl**

**Note:**
I use tomcat.
I use the flowing config:

```
    <jpa:repositories base-package="com.sanatech.repository" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.my.repository"/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.my.domin.impl"/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.my.domin"/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.my"/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.my.manageuser.controller"/>
    <tx:annotation-driven/>
    <context:annotation-config />
```

**Edit**

when I separated the unit test to a new project and added reference to the data layer jar in the build bath I found the same exception.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure this exception is't raised from your testcase:

```
public class testcase1 {

    @Autowired
private UserImpl userImpl;
```

You can explicitly set bean name in @Service annotation and use this name in @Autowired to make sure of correct configuration.